# how to add a script data using mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i was using an image gallery like this

```
<script>
            Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            Galleria.run('.galleria');
        </script>
```

now i want to use MVC 4, so please how to add the data of `scripts` which are the two statments into my view?

#### i tried puting them in this

```
@section scripts {

}
```

but nothing works

any help?()

Answer (score 0):

Putting them in @section scripts should work.

I have had issues where I needed to enclose them in a $(document).ready(function() {});  so now  I always enclose my startup scripts in the document ready function.

```
@section scripts {
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.run('.galleria');
  });
  </script>
}
```

This will make sure the document is fully loaded before executing the script.

If you are not adding jquery in a shared template you may want to add

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

on your page as well.

Also remember to put `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` in your layout page if it is not present.